# Printing Issue using ftw and process to print out directory size and its path name

Tags: c, linux

Here is what I am trying to do:

> Write a C program using two processes (one parent, one child). Child process goes through entire directory and sends the path of dir along with its size to the parent and the parent prints out the info like this "dir size \tdirpath".

This is what I have so far:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static int dirSize = 0;
char *dirPath = NULL;
static int dirInfo(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf){
    dirSize = sb -> st_size;
    dirPath = fpath;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t processCheck[1];
    int i = 0;
    int pipes[1][2];
    char *directoryPath = argv[1];

    processCheck[1] = fork();
    if(processCheck[1]==0){
        close(pipes[i][0]);
        nftw(directoryPath, dirInfo, 10, FTW_PHYS);
        write(pipes[i][1], &dirSize, sizeof dirSize);
        write(pipes[i][1], &dirPath, sizeof dirPath);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(pipes[i][1]);
    int childProcessStatus;
    if(WIFEXITED(childProcessStatus)&&WEXITSTATUS(childProcessStatus)==0){
        int v;
        char * d;
        if(read(pipes[i][0], &v, sizeof v) == sizeof(v)){
            printf("%d\t" , v);
        }
        if(read(pipes[i][0], &d, sizeof d) == sizeof(d)){
            printf("%s\n", d);
        }
    }
    close(pipes[i][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Issue: the program is compiling and running but it is not printing anything. Also I need to sort the directories by their size using hash map, linked list, or  a tree in the parent process simultaneously with the child process

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious error is that you didn't create a pipe. You need to add this line above the `fork`:

```
    pipe(pipes[i]);
```

Another error (or at least *Undefined Behaviour* which in most cases is the same thing) is that `processCheck` is an array of length 1 which means that when you try to access `processCheck[1]` you've gone past its end.

Comment: it is not working it is only printing 4096      4096

Comment: i tried inputting several other directories but i get the same output

Comment: it has to print all the directories size and pathname